# Mystique theme: widgets on sidebar falling under the page content

Tags: themes, sidebar

I'm using the default two columns layout of the Mystique theme.
If I insert widgets into the main sidebar from the dashboard, instead of being showed aside in the page, they fall under the post (even overlapping the comment box).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are they _failing_ or do they _fall_?

Comment: Please link to the theme in question and (if possible) to a live site displaying the issue. Not that presentations issues like you describe are often just CSS and as such are not in scope here.

Comment: @kaiser: they are placed under the page/article content

Answer (score 1):

Your theme has html code errors or you have introduced some with errors in your widgets.

Use http://validator.w3.org/ to check for code errors, especially missing closing `</div>` tags. Missing a `</div>` will drop sidebars and widgets below the content `<div>`.

And use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to test and change the CSS and HTML.